# play multiple wav file in android with sequentially

Tags: java, android

I have five  `wav`
file in raw folder android.

How I can play this with sequentially?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please extend your question and show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

Declare Media Player Object.

```
MediaPlayer objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,Your Music File //ex:-R.raw.sleepaway);
```

then you can add Several Media Player Methods for controlling behavior of Media Player.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
objPlayer.start();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
}
return 1;
}

public void onStop(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
public void onPause(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
```

you can change the Audio file from onStop or onPause Method. and start again with new Audio.